# How do I separate values of a column into another column based on a specific column in an R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

In my example df:

| id | site |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 426 |
| 1 | 452 |
| 2 | 118 |
| 2 | 300 |

How can I separate site values into another column based on id values to achieve something like this:

| id | site1 | site2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 426 | 452 |
| 2 | 118 | 300 |

dfA <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), Site = c(426, 452, 118, 300))

I'm not sure how to execute the code, my goal is to get merge all id values into one row.